# Workaround for the grey area around the map on zoom out

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using Google Maps Javascript API for rendering a map. When we zoom out on the map there is a brief moment that we see a grey area (while waiting for new tiles). Is there any workaround for this behavior in order to provide a similar user experience as mobile devices (Google Maps SDK Android and Iphone), where we always see a map on zoom out and not that brief grey area around the map?

Answer (score 0):

The grey area around the map exists because it takes time to access the image tiles over the Internet connection from the server. My presumptiosn as to the reason why the mobile version does not do this are either that they have a special function that accesses the cache instead of re-querying the image on mobile, or that mobile simply *has* a built-in cache of, say, the entire world at zoom levels 0-3.

In other words, I do not know of a way to avoid the grey space. To get a work-around would require re-writing a good portion of Google's code, specifically to access the browser's cache. Even if you did succeed, a first-time user of the webpage would still get the grey space simply because a cache does not already exist.

My advice is to ignore it, as it is "brief" (and likely will not have much of any impact on the user experience), and that there are no easy fixes.

Comment: I agree with you and the assumptions you have and I will ignore this issue for the web project I'm working on, because it is seen as acceptable by the users. But for a hybrid solution (Android and Iphone) this behaviour won't be that acceptable. Well, I guess I'll have to live with this!